# Lotus Notes combobox not showing backend values

Tags: combobox, lotus-notes

I have a agent (running on a server) which creates Notes documents, populating the backend fields as it goes. Obviously, the agent has no access to uidoc as there is no frontend here. When I come to open the documents in the UI, all the fields are populated, except for comboboxes which fail to pick up the selection from the backend value. It also looks as though the act of opening the document alone is wiping out the value I know to be stored in the underlying document.

The agent works something like this: (typed from memory)

```
set nd = db.createdocument()
nd.form = "some form"
nd.somefield = "some value"
nd.combobox = "apples"
nd.save true true
```

When I examine nd in the debugger, the combobox contains the "apples" selection. When I open the document in the UI however, and use something like

```
msgbox uidoc.document.combobox(0)
```

The field is now empty (but 'somefield' contains 'some value' as expected). As far as I can tell, I can't do a refresh or reload when the document is created, it's almost as though I need to do it when the document is first opened in the UI, because it seems that something is refreshing the backend as SOON as I open the document in the UI.

PS. I know 'apples' exists as a choice in the combobox, so why doesn't the combobox selection now reflect this choice. Just to be doubly sure, it's not the available choices I'm trying to work with but the selection that the user made.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How have you defined the combobox values? Are they set by a formula or a fixed list? And do they have aliases? Do you have the "allow values not in list" box selected? Can you add a pic of the field properties box showing how you set this up? Also, have looked at the field list in doc properties to verify that the name and value of your combobox field are correct? Have you compared it to what you see if you just create the doc manually and select "apples"?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this is a timing issue when opening the document. 
Comboboxes have choice values that are defined in the properties of the field.

These can be "fixed" values or computed from some source.

If the calculation of the field is BEFORE the calculation of the choice values, then the field will be empty, as only values from the choices are kept, everything else is removed. Order of calculation would then be:

- choices are empty
- field empties itself, because @ThisValue is not in the list of choices
- choices are populated
- now apple would be in choices, but it is already empty

In that case: Please make sure, that the choices in EVERY CASE contain the field- values by doing something like this in the choices- formula:

```
_choices := ... do your calculation here
@If( !@Contains( _choices ; @ThisValue ) ; _choices : @ThisValue ; _choices )
```

Another possibility for your value to be deleted is, that you use aliases in the choices. If your choices look like this:

```
Apples|A
Bananas|B
Pines|P
```

And you put "Apples" in the field in the backend, then it will be emptied on document open. Then you would have to put the alias in the field: `nd.combobox = "A"`